# C structures and functions

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I am trying to create a function that adds values to a structure but it does not return anything.
This function is meant to allow the user to add records.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
struct Produit {
    int Num;
    char Nom[50];
    char Description[100];
    float Prix;
} s[10];

void add(struct Produit s[],int n);
void display(struct Produit s[],int p,int n)

int main {
    add(s,1); 
    display(s,1);
    ++n;
}

void add(struct Produit s[], int n){
    again:
      printf("\nEntrez le nom du produit à ajouter:");
      scanf("%s",s[n].Nom);
      if(searchP(s,s[n].Nom,n)!=-1){
      printf("Déjà existant\n");goto again;
    }
    
    printf("Entrez la description :");
    scanf("%s",&s[n].Description);
    printf("Entrez le prix :");
    scanf("%f",&s[n].Prix);
}

void display(struct Produit s[],int p,int n) {
    printf("Nom du produit: ");
    puts(s[p-1].Nom);
    printf("Description: ");
    puts(s[p-1].Description);
    printf("Prix: %.1f", s[p-1].Prix);
    printf("\n");
}
```

When I run this it works fine but when I verify if the record that I've entered is is there I don't find anything. I try to display the record but it's empty.
it returns this :

```
Entrez le nom du produit α ajouter:pen
Entrez la description :red
Entrez le prix :1.99
Nom du produit:
Description:
Prix: 0.0
```

can anyone tell what is wrong. thanks
PS : The function SearchP is working fine in other parts of the code so I don't think it is the problem, but nonetheless here is it.

```
int searchP(struct Produit s[],char Name[], int n) {
    
    int found =-1,i;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1 && found==-1; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(s[i].Nom,Name)==0) {
            found=i;
        }    
        else 
            found=-1;
  }

return found;
}
```

Comment: How do you call `add` function? because `++n;` inside `add` function has no effect.

Comment: needs the full, minimised code showing the problem, including how you output what you showed.

Comment: I have updated the post to include the whole code.

Comment: My old favorite, `scanf()` of user input without checking the return code -> undefined behavior waiting to happen.

Comment: `while (p<1 || p>n )   printf("Numéro introuvable");` is a no op (if the condition is false) or an endless loop (if the condition is true).

Comment: `goto` isn't a good thing to use. In `add` you could use `do ... while` instead of it.

Comment: I understand. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code that works better but **still needs some work.**

As already commented you need a global counter for the `s` array (here: `nbp`).
There also one-off errors when searching into `s`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
struct Produit {
    int Num;
    char Nom[50];
    char Description[100];
    float Prix;
} s[10];

int nbp = 0;


void display(struct Produit s[],int p) {
    printf("Nom du produit: ");
    puts(s[p].Nom);
    printf("Description: ");
    puts(s[p].Description);
    printf("Prix: %.1f", s[p].Prix);
    printf("\n");
}


void add(struct Produit s[]);


int searchP(struct Produit s[],char Name[]) {
    
    int found =-1,i;
    for (i = 0; i < nbp && found==-1; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(s[i].Nom,Name)==0) {
            found=i;
        }    
        else 
            found=-1;
  }
return found;
}

int main () {

    add(s); 
    display(s, 0);
    return 0;
}

void add(struct Produit s[]){
    again:
      printf("\nEntrez le nom du produit à ajouter:");
      scanf("%s",s[nbp].Nom);
      if(searchP(s,s[nbp].Nom)!=-1){
      printf("Déjà existant\n");goto again;
    }
    
    printf("Entrez la description :");
    scanf("%s",s[nbp].Description);
    printf("Entrez le prix :");
    scanf("%f",&s[nbp].Prix);
 

   nbp++;
}
```

Execution:

```
./myprog

Entrez le nom du produit à ajouter:Nom
Entrez la description :Desc
Entrez le prix :1
Nom du produit: Nom
Description: Desc
Prix: 1.0
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more. what was the one-off error?

Comment: In a C array with `n` items you must loop from `0` to `n-1`: first item has index `0` and last item has index `n-1`. In `searchP` you must have something like `for (i=0; i < n ....`).

Comment: When using `scanf` with a string declared as `char *` you should not take again the address of the string but just pass the string name because it's already a pointer. This error can be checked by the compiler with some flags for example `gcc -Wall ...`.